# Add thumnail image for search result in solr

Tags: solr

I want to add thumbnail image for some of search result in solr/browse,how can i do that for solr 3.3 or 3.4?

Comment: How you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can store the thumbnail url in your index. but there is no need to make it searchable